# При отправке не заполненной form закрывается модальное окно

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, submit, required

Помогите разобраться с решением проблемы - есть форма на сайте, которая отправляет сообщения в бот телеграмма, но перед отправкой она должна проверять заполненность всех полей - обязательно. Пробовал с html атрибут - **required** он не работал, а вообще писали что браузеры типо Safari могут игнорировать, поэтому выбор пал на скрипт через **jquery**, а именно: **parsley**. Я нашёл в документации нужный атрибут, прописал всё как нужно в input и оно работает, вот только проблема при нажатии на кнопку - **Отправить**, если пустые поля он сообщение не отправит в бот и закроет форму. И при повторном её открытии можно будет увидеть подпись: *поля не заполнены*. Как сделать, что окошко формы после нажатии на кнопку не закрывалось?
Прилагаю код формы:

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="POST" action="./php/telegrambot.php">
<div class="modal-body bg-light">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <label class="form-label"><b>Имя:</b></label>
                <input class="form-control" maxlength="20" id="FirstNameInput" placeholder="Иван" name="FirstName" data-parsley-required="true"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label"><b>Контактный номер:</b></label>
                <input class="form-control" maxlength="11" id="PhoneInput" placeholder="89198987109" name="Phone" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="digits"></div>
    </div>
</div>
                    
<div class="modal-footer bg-danger border-top border-primary border-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary border-2 text-nowrap me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Отправить</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Так подключаю файлы в теле Body:

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/parsley.js"></script>
```

Так под ними ниже пишу скрипт:

```
<script>
    $('#form').parsley();
</script>
```

Comment: Вам надо повесить событие клика на кнопку. По клику остановить отправку формы, выполнить валидацию. Если валидация пройдена, отправить, если нет, то нет(модалка останется с надписями). Все это можно сделать с помощью javaScript, ну и jQuery тоже.